Couldn't install 'marketingcloudsdk-ios' 8.1.0 with exact version?
This error is appears to me "Showing Recent Issues Failed to resolve dependencies Dependencies could not be resolved because no versions of 'marketingcloudsdk-ios' match the requirement 8.1.0 and root depends on 'marketingcloudsdk-ios' 8.1.0."
keep in note:-

this version is already working with my team normally
trying to install this version on other project (new project) and the same error couldn't check the attachment
Xcode version 15.4
MacOS 14.5, Apple M3 Pro

 
